# Hard drive making weird sounds

Tags: hard-drive

I just tried to save an image file that I made and my hard drive sounded like a jet engine firing up, but more "buzz-ish", and now it's just making a buzzing sound. Is that a bad thing? This also happens when my computer boots up.
A possible reason that this might be happening is that the hard drive might be leaning against something - maybe I didn't install it correctly in my case?

Comment: Are you sure it's the hard drive and not one of the fans?  A hard drive with a bad bearing can make noise, but what you describe is more like a CPU fan with a wire touching the blades -- starting up because the processor is going into faster clock and the system is initiating more aggressive cooling.

Comment: @ZeissIkon It's possible, but would a CPU fan make a buzzing and rumbling sound? I'll see what sort of sounds are made when I install my SSD.

Comment: I've got a case fan that sometimes gets a wire into it and make a buzzing, rumbling sound.  Just saying that fans, with exposed blades, are much more likely sources of that kind of noise than a hard disk; generally if a hard disk bearing is failing, you'll get a S.M.A.R.T. alert -- because it'll also take too long to come up to speed, have spindle speed variations that cause read/write errors, and other issues.

Comment: could be a screw tightening issue? perhaps its vibrating the metal casing when the drive is seeking..?